# filter an array of nested objects in 5 level

Tags: javascript

I am trying filter this array with .filter.

```js
var objList = [
  {
    "name": "Object0Name",
    "id": "Object0ID",
    "Object1List": [
      {
        "id": "Object1id_A1",
        "name": "Object1Name_A1",
        "Object2List": [
          {
            "id": 187,
            "name": "Object2Name_A1",
            "Object3List": [
              {
                "id": "mammal",
                "name": "mammal",
                "Object4List": [
                  {
                    "id_client": "rabbit",                   
                    "Currency": "EUR"  
                  },
                  {
                    "id_client": "cat",                    
                    "Currency": "EUR",
                  },
                  {
                    "id_client": "tiger",
                    "Currency": "EUR",                    
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "Object1id_B1",
        "name": "Object1Name_B1",
        "Object2List": [
          {
            "id": 189,
            "name": "Object2Name_B1",
            "Object3List": [
              {
                "id": "fish",
                "name": "fish",
                "Object4List": [
                  {
                    "id_client": "tiger shark",                   
                    "Currency": "EUR",
                    
                  },
                  {
                    "id_client": "tuna",
                    "currency": "GBP",                   
                  },
                  
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

var response= objList.filter(function(Object0List){
   return Object0List.Object1List.filter(function(Object1List){
    return  Object1List.Object2List.filter(function(Object2List){
     return  Object2List.Object3List.filter(function(Object3List){
      return  Object3List.Object4List.filter(function(Object4List){
       return Object4List.id_client==="tiger shark";

      });
     });
    });
   });
  });



var myJSON = JSON.stringify(response);
console.log('The animal is:');
console.log(myJSON);
```

But the filter doesn't work. I am receiving all objects. I must receive:
[
  {
    "name": "Object0Name",
    "id": "Object0ID",
    "Object1List": [

```
  {
    "id": "Object1id_B1",
    "name": "Object1Name_B1",
    "Object2List": [
      {
        "id": 189,
        "name": "Object2Name_B1",
        "Object3List": [
          {
            "id": "fish",
            "name": "fish",
            "Object4List": [
              {
                "id_client": "tiger shark",                   
                "Currency": "EUR",

              }                 

            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

}
]

Could someone help me find out what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure the problem is that I'm using the .filter function badly but it took several hours and I'm not capable of fixing it. I think that I do not understand this function for nested objects, I tried to filter the array of nested objects with lambda expressions but I'm also not able.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: What do you want to get? All objects that contain the searched word and their parents?

Comment: You want to get tiger shark and all parrents?

Comment: And why do you name the keys `"Object1List", "Object2List"` instead of just `children` ?

Comment: Hi Jonas W and Artur. Yes, I want to get all the objects that contain the searched word and their parents

Comment: Hi Jonas, I don't know. Call it as you want, it would also be valid children1list and children2list

Comment: Hi Jonas ,I would not give it the name "children " because it is not an object it is a list of objects and for this reason I give the name of children1list

Comment: Your filter works correctly, but it returns all of the elements of `objList` which somewhere in its child properties has a child Element in `Object4List` with id "tiger shark". and so it returns the whole object in `objList`. for it to do what you want, you need to loop over all lists and filter just `Object4List` and assign it back to `Object4List` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check each property which is an array and take only filtered values.

This approach mutates the original array.

```js
function filter(array, value) {
    var temp = array.filter(o =>
        Object.keys(o).some(k => {
            var t = filter(Array.isArray(o[k]) ? o[k] : [], value);
            if (o[k] === value) {
                return true;
            }
            if (t && Array.isArray(t) && t.length) {
                o[k] = t;
                return true;
            }
        })
    );
    if (temp.length) {
        return temp;
    }
}

var array = [{ name: "Object0Name", id: "Object0ID", Object1List: [{ id: "Object1id_A1", name: "Object1Name_A1", Object2List: [{ id: 187, name: "Object2Name_A1", Object3List: [{ id: "mammal", name: "mammal", Object4List: [{ id: "rabbit", Currency: "EUR" }, { id: "cat", Currency: "EUR" }, { id: "tiger", Currency: "EUR" }] }] }] }, { id: "Object1id_B1", name: "Object1Name_B1", Object2List: [{ id: 189, name: "Object2Name_B1", Object3List: [{ id: "fish", name: "fish", Object4List: [{ id: "tiger shark", Currency: "EUR" }, { id: "tuna", currency: "GBP" }] }] }] }] }],
    result = filter(array, 'tiger shark');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Nina, your function is valid, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that every of your objects has this structure:

```
  {
   id: "sth",
   name: "whatever"
   children: [ /***/ ]
  }
```

So then it is quite easy to filter recursively:

```
 function filter(arr, search){
   const result = [];
   for(const {name, id, children} of arr){
     children = filter(children, search);
     if(children.length || id === search)
       result.push({id, name, children });
   }
   return result;
 }
```

Usable as:

```
  var response = filter(objList, "tiger shark");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but the name of the id is not the same, so it can not be recursive. In the example I'm wrong and I name all identical ids, I've changed it now (In the Object4List the id is name id_client now) I am so sorry by the mistake